# Is it possible to use an sms: url to pre-fill a message with a body but no recipient?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I'd like to create a "Share via SMS" button using Javascript that will open up the user's messages app (e.g., on iOS or Android) with the body pre-filled, but the recipient left empty. There's a lot of conflicting information about what URL scheme to use for this, and whether it's even possible.

I've been testing this out on my Mac, and haven't been able to get it to work fully. What I've tried:

This opens a new tab with a prompt to open the Messages app, but does nothing when I allow it:

```
window.open('sms:&body=text')
```

This opens the Messages app with "text" correctly filled in the body, but "?" as the recipient:

```
window.open('sms:?&body=text')
```

This opens the Messages app with "text" filled in as the recipient:

```
window.open('sms:;body=text')
```

I've found posts that suggest this was once possible (e.g., http://blog.julianklotz.de/the-sms-uri-scheme/), but am suspecting that it no longer is. Can anyone confirm that, or if it is possible, let me know that what the correct syntax is?

Comment: I use the `<a`> tag --   IE `<a href="sms://+19999999999?body=I%27m%20Some%20Test%20Text%20For%20Your%20A%20Tag">Send SMS</a>`  BUT -- I assume the formatting is the same ..

Answer (score 1):

I want to share the solution I found by reading this article:
https://jsmobiledev.com/article/sms-link/

One thing to add inside of either the html tag or the JS method is a '&' after the '?' as shown below. I tested this and after trying the previous methods and it is now working

```
window.open("sms://?&body=hey%20there");
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that this is working:

```
<div onClick="window.open('sms://+19999999999?body=I%27m%20Some%20Test%20Text%20For%20Your%20A%20Tag')">
    SEND SMS
</div>
```

Your formatting was a little off .. Remember that you are going to want to URL encode .. So things like spaces become `%20` and things like single quotes become `%27` etc etc etc

**CONVERSELY** -- You can also throw it in an `<a>` tag as well ..  Like --

```
<a href="sms://+19999999999?body=I%27m%20Some%20Test%20Text%20For%20Your%20A%20Tag">Send SMS</a>
```

And it will work the same way ...

**UPDATE**  -- This will open the SMS app ask for a recipient and pre-fill the text --

```
<a href="sms://?body=I%27m%20Some%20Test%20Text%20For%20Your%20A%20Tag">Send SMS</a>
```

OR

```
<div onClick="window.open('sms://?body=I%27m%20Some%20Test%20Text%20For%20Your%20A%20Tag')">
    SEND SMS
</div>
```

Comment: This is including the phone number, which I don't want to do.

Comment: See update answer ..  Both tested and working properly

Comment: What platform are you using to test that? If I do something like window.open('sms://?body=Sometext'), on MacOS, it opens up Messages with '?body=Sometext' in the recipient field; on iOS the Messages app fails to open at all.